# How do I clone a mouseevent for $emit in vue

Tags: javascript, events

I am trying to

- emit an event from a vue2 component
- have the event reflect exactly the native mouse event happening in the component
- and have two fields added - canvasX and canvasX

I tried adding the fields like this:

```
evt.canvasX = x;
evt.canvasY = y;
```

and emitting like this:

```
this.$emit('mouseup', evt)
```

but in the handler in the outer component there is no trace of canvasX and canvasX

Barring copying all properties one by one - is there a way to extend the event with new properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a new event data object which inherits properties from the original event.

```js
this.$emit('mouseup', { ...evt, canvasX: x, canvasY: y })
```